# Examples not returning message to client

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to follow [this](http://www.programwitherik.com/socket-io-tutorial-with-node-js-and-express/) example, but I don't see the message "Hello World from client" on the brower. For that matter, I don't see the `Client connected...`.

I do see the Hello World and the form .

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');  
var app = express();  
var server = require('http').createServer(app);  
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components')); 

io.on('connection', function(client) {  
    console.log('Client connected...');

    client.on('join', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        client.emit('messages', 'Hello from server');
    });
});    

app.get('/', function(req, res,next) {  
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});    

server.listen(4200);
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>  
<html lang="en"> 
    <script>  
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4200');
        socket.on('connect', function(data) {
            socket.emit('join', 'Hello World from client');
        });
        socket.on('messages', function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    </script> 
    <head>       
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <div id="future"></div>
        <form id="form" id="chat_form">
            <input id="chat_input" type="text">
            <input type="submit" value="Send">
        </form>
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>            
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<script>` tag just could resides in `<head>` or `<body>` tags. If you are going to manipulating the dom and not using a *DomReady* function to check whether the dom is ready or not, then you should place all your script tags at the end of your body tag just before `</body>`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>My App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <div id="future"></div>
    <form id="chat_form">
      <input id="chat_input" type="text">
      <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4200');
      socket.on('connect', function(data) {
        socket.emit('join', 'Hello World from client');
      });
      socket.on('messages', function(data) {
        alert(data);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```